# Android best practice when accessing APIs and navigation

Tags: android, api, thread-safety

Let say that I have two Activity to develop in Android.  Upon the end user click a button in Activity A, the application supposed to pull data off a JSON API and present that information on Activity B.

So my question is, what's the best practice or pattern?  i.e.

1. **Activity A** will call an AsyncTask and perform JSON call.  Pull the data, push it into the Intent via putExtra, and call **Activity B**?
2. **Activity A** will call Activity B, **Activity B** onCreate will call an AsyncTask and perform the JSON call?
3. Other suggestions?

Which one is the prefer pattern?

And which gives better user experience?  (e.g. imagine where the error dialog will be if connection fail to the server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think normally something of your #2 approach is done. In most cases, though, you need to tell Activity B what type of information to request from the JSON API. So say in Activity A you are choosing an item from a list, and Activity B will get more information about that item. In this example Activity A will simply pass a reference to which item was selected, and then Activity B can use that reference to make a JSON request for more information about that item. Does that make sense?

I usually try to pass as little information as I can in Intent extras so I would steer clear of your first solution.